# Creating a new array from first x out of each y rows in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, subset

I have an array of power output data for a national grid at 15 minute intervals over the course of a year (24*4*365 therefore 35040x1 array)

Each day therefore represents 96 datapoints. I want to take out only the data from 0000-0800 each day and create a new 11680x1 array.

How do I take out the first 1-32 rows out of each 96? I've tried this but it only iterates once.

```
M = csvread('NI generation 2013.csv',1,4,[1,4,35039,4]);
low = 97;
high = 192;
data = M(1:34, 1);

for i = M(low:high,1)
    N = M(low:(low+33),1);
    data = [data;N];
    low = low+96;
    high = high+96;

end
data
```

EDIT: This worked.

```
array = csvread('NI generation 2013.csv',1,4,[1,4,35039,4]);
new_array = [];
for n = 1:((length(array)/96)+1)
    idx = (n-1)*96 + (1:32);
    new_array = [new_array; array(idx)];
    end
    new_array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anything fancy, a `for` loop should do it. for example

```
array = rand(35040,1);
new_array = [];
for n = 1:length(array)/96
    idx = (n-1)*96 + (1:32);
    new_array = [new_array; array(idx)];
end
```

You might have to change it a little, but this will get you started.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! only one tiny mod needed.

couldn't make code work here so have edited above.

Comment: Great! If it takes too long you should optimize it by preallocating `new_array` and making an `idx2` so that inside the loop you use `new_array(idx2) = array(idx);` that will be WAY faster and is better practice